# Why is this guy handcuffed censored?

Tags: uchi-no-maid-ga-uzasugiru

In episode 5 of *Uchi no Maid ga Uzasugiru!*, at around 12:04, there's a guy who was handcuffed after being found out asking for low-angle pics from young kids. However, the handcuff was being censored with mosaic.

[image: the handcuffed being censored with mosaic]

Aren't kids/teens supposed to watch people get arrested or it's just an exaggeration? Or are they hiding other than the handcuff?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's probably no reason for in-universe, but this represents the current norm in Japan: **In Japanese broadcasts, handcuffs are usually censored to prevent the guilty feeling of the arrested person.**

In Japan, when a person is arrested, they are always considered as a *suspect* first, regardless if they self-admit the crime or not. The handcuffs seen by other people will make the arrested person *looks guilty* and may affect the trial. Even though there is the [presumption of innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence) (a suspect is always presumed as innocent until proven guilty), the handcuffs may imply the suspect as already guilty. Even though the suspect is judged as *not guilty*, the guilty impression from the handcuffs may still linger on the observers.

This norm started after the case of [Kazuyoshi Miura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuyoshi_Miura_(businessman)) who had been arrested but successfully brought a case to the court that him being pictured in handcuffs implied guilt and had prejudiced the trial.

This is also the reason why a suspect's head & hands are usually covered with a cloth/towel when arrested in Japan.

---

Sources:

- [Wikipedia - National regulations regarding depiction of handcuffed people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handcuffs#National_regulations_regarding_depiction_of_handcuffed_people)
- [The UI Junkie - What’s Up With the Blurred Or Pixelated Handcuffs In Japan, France And South Korea?](https://theuijunkie.com/pixelated-handcuffs-japan/)
- [Everything2 - Why Japanese TV mosaics out handcuffs](https://everything2.com/title/Why+Japanese+TV+mosaics+out+handcuffs)
- [Quora - Why do police officers sometimes cover the hands of the handcuffed person with a cloth or towel (as seen in many arrest scenes in Japanese & S. Korean Movies/dramas)?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-police-officers-sometimes-cover-the-hands-of-the-handcuffed-person-with-a-cloth-or-towel-as-seen-in-many-arrest-scenes-in-Japanese-S-Korean-Movies-dramas/answer/Zachary-Yamada-2)